# Proper implementation of SignalR in a standard ASP.Net web application (Non-MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Am currently developing a normal web application using site.master page for the layouts.

I noticed, when implementing SignalR, we have to import the following scripts

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

However, is it a good practice to place the scripts in the site.master, considering the connection would start multiple times.

Is there a better way to import the scripts in a more general place where it will only start the hub once? Or does it not matter at all if I leave it in my site.master page?

Also, what happens if I have different pages that do not use the site.master, in that case, do I need to re-import the scripts in the different page?

Comment: Just trying to understand. Are you working on classic asp web forms? Does your project has files with ".asp" or ".aspx" extensions? Not sure what this has to do with SignalR. Looks like you are just looking for a way to reference some js scripts in some subset of your pages.

Comment: aspx, and yes. I want to integrate SignalR into my Asp.net web application. I was wondering if placing these scripts in my site.master page is the most efficient way to achieve it. It may be working, but I want the most optimized solution for such scenario. Is it even a good practice to start the same hub multiple times in the application?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that comes to mind.

Implementing nested master page. [See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/nested-master-pages-cs) You can add scripts in inner master page and use this master page only for the pages where you need these additional scripts. This is a "ok" approach if there are a lot of pages that needs this script (but not all).

You could also create a content place holder in master template. like this.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphScripts" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then in the pages where you want to add extra scripts you can add scripts like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentScripts" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphScripts" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

I would take this approach if you have few pages where you need these scripts. As you can see you have to repeat the block again and again in every page.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if SignalR hub's connection is started a few times?

Comment: You should be fine if you load one script only once per web page. SignalR is smart enough to "smartly" handle multiple hub connection request.